# Code in Razor files

Tags: razor

I wanted to ask a simple question (since my recent difficult questions haven't received any answers :-)).  When we write code in Razor files like this

```
@{
 // code
}
```

Does this code get executed on the server, because I can't imagine it being executed on the client side.

Comment: Yes it will get execute on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, code blocks located in markup with @ are executed on the server.

Check out this primer on Razor:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx